# Implement SiriKit/Google Assistant in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, google-assistant-sdk, sirikit

I haven't been able to find any resources on integrating SiriKit in Flutter. I checked out the [Writing custom platform-specific code](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-swift-tab) but I'm not sure how to apply that for SiriKit. I understand the concept, but do I need to create custom intents or just provide platform channels (Android/iOS)
What I want to do is have the user be able to use Siri or Google Assistant to open the app which will then invoke an action (start a video call). Is this possible?

Comment: Even I'm trying to implement the same. Did you able to implement it?

Comment: I never found a solution, unfortunately we had to leave out that feature.